# Append element to editor in visual studio extension

Tags: visual-studio, editor, element

I am working in visual studio extension and I want to add some visual element to 
Visual studio editor. But I can't find the way to do that. Please help me, Thank you very much!

I append some image about my idea below:

- CodeLen include some text:[CodeLen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JahG.png)
- OzCode include visual element on debug:[OzCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T4Ho.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958099/how-to-augment-the-visual-studio-c-sharp-editor-with-non-textual-information

Comment: Thank you  Sergey Vlasov. I will find the way to solve my problems base on you answer and I will post my solution after It done

Comment: Hi @SergeyVlasov ,I was investigate you aswer.  " Intra-Text Adornment Sample" look like what I need but I cannot find how to add a tagger at bottom or top of the text (like OzCode). Could you help me a little bit more? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution base on answer of @Sergey Vlasov.

- For adornment on top, bottom or every where of text you should define `ColorAdornment` inherit `Canvas`
- For margin the text with other line you should use `bottomSpace` on contructor of `IntraTextAdornmentTag`.
- You can find solution at: https://github.com/thuantan2060/intra-textadornment